# search using text and delete node jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my DOM

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>random text</p>
<p>765</p>
<p>whatever</p>
<p>http://www.google.com</p>
<p>hello world</p>
```

and the http://www.google.com can be anywhere so there is no fixed pattern then I can't use nth-child. One way is loop through but is there any advantage if it's wrapped by a div? or we still have to loop?

Comment: i dont get your question, what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I think he wants to find the <p> with the google text, and is asking if he can do so without looping through the entire dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:contains` should work for your use case:

```
$("p:contains('http://www.google.com')").remove()
```

If you wanted to be more strict, you could use a combination of filter & text:

```
$("p").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === "http://www.google.com";
}).remove();
```

Both of these solutions use a loop internally, but of course most(all?) solutions will. It just looks prettier.

Comment: does the contain do like indexOf? coz it could be http://yahoo.com.. assume http is a repeated pattern but the rest is not, will :contain still work?

Comment: Contains is more akin to a search with indexof so any path under the Google domain would match, however you might want to use filter along with a regex if you want to match any URL

Answer (score 1):

:contains  selector is what youre looking for http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
alert($( "p:contains('http://www.google.com')" )
```